# Событие изменения цветовой схемы MS Office 2010

Tags: c#, office

В офисе есть три цветовые схемы: Blue, Silver, Black. 
Как можно подписаться на событие изменения значения цветовые схемы?
Требуется это для того, чтобы собственные компоненты были в одной цветовой гаме с офисом.

Answer (score 3):

- Судя по [**этом треду,**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1377966/event-when-word-2007-changes-the-theme) никаких событий в `SDK` для этого не зарезервировано.
- Соответственно, остается вариант с `poll'ингом` соответствующей ветки реестра или вариант, когда ваша цветовая схема устанавливается только при старте и не реагирует на изменение темы в настройках `Microsoft Office`.